# Choosing a file from explorer and insert his name in python script using os.start() or Subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, windows

The user clicks on button and windows explorer opens. So how can i pick a file from explorer using Subprocess.Popen() or os.start() and insert its name to variable? Thank you for help

Comment: What you had tried to do that? Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly. :)

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with Windows Explorer started from `subprocess` because what you want is for Explorer to do a callback to your code. Windows Explorer extensions cannot do much more than add an icon or a context menu entry. What you can do is use your UI framework's file picker dialogue (such as `wxPython.FileDialog` or `tkinter.filedialog`) to let your user select a file in a way that your program knows about.